# How to add an empty row to GridView programmatically:

Tags: android, gridview, row, adapter, android-gridview

I know this question have been asked a few times, and I know that what you will say is that the GridView as with the ListView object is also backed up by an adapter implementation that should populate the rows of the grid.

**My requirement is as follows:** I have a gridview of emoticons, that are displayed when I press on one of the buttons on the keyboard I develop. As part of this emoticons gridview I have a view of buttons at the bottom of it to allow the user to continue working with the keyboard (buttons like space, delete, go back to regular keyboard and others...)

**Now I want to add an empty row to the gridview so I can allow the user to choose the emoticons on the last row of the grid** (If I won't add this row the last row of the gird view is behind the additional buttons view and can't be selected) Here is an example:

[image: Emoticons keyboard screenshot]

As you can see here the last row is behind the additional buttons view and can't be pressed. I can't just add an arbitrary number of empty icons to the gridview as the number of icons in a row is changing when moving from one device to another.

So the question is how can I add an empty row to this gridview with no regards to the number of items in the row?

Here is my code:

```
public class EmojiconGridView{
public View rootView;
EmojiconsPopup mEmojiconPopup;
EmojiconRecents mRecents;
Emojicon[] mData;

public EmojiconGridView(Context context, Emojicon[] emojicons, EmojiconRecents recents, EmojiconsPopup emojiconPopup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mEmojiconPopup = emojiconPopup;
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.emojicon_grid, null);
    setRecents(recents);
     GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Emoji_GridView);
        if (emojicons== null) {
            mData = People.DATA;
        } else {
            Object[] o = (Object[]) emojicons;
            mData = Arrays.asList(o).toArray(new Emojicon[o.length]);
        }
        EmojiAdapter mAdapter = new EmojiAdapter(rootView.getContext(), mData);
        mAdapter.setEmojiClickListener(new OnEmojiconClickedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onEmojiconClicked(Emojicon emojicon) {
                if (mEmojiconPopup.onEmojiconClickedListener != null) {
                    mEmojiconPopup.onEmojiconClickedListener.onEmojiconClicked(emojicon);
                }
                if (mRecents != null) {
                    mRecents.addRecentEmoji(rootView.getContext(), emojicon);
                }
            }
        });
        gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        View newEmpryView = new View(context);
        gridView.addView(newEmpryView);

}

private void setRecents(EmojiconRecents recents) {
    mRecents = recents;
}

public interface OnEmojiconClickedListener {
    void onEmojiconClicked(Emojicon emojicon);
}
```

}

Clearly the row:

```
 gridView.addView(newEmpryView);
```

gives me an exception of: : `addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView`, So how can this be accomplished? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your layout? I guess you need to use layout_below or use verrical linearlayout to handle that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add a blank items to last row in your GridView and like this you get a blank row.

to get the number of columns in your GridView you can use the following code:

```
private int getNumColumnsCompat(Context aContext) {
        DisplayMetrics d = aContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int w = d.widthPixels;
        float density = d.density;
        int num = (int) (w / (40 * density)) - 1; // 40 is the columnWidth of your Emoji_GridView
        return num;
    }
```

after that add a blank row to your GridView like this following code:

```
private void addItemsToList(int aNumColumnsCompat) {
        for (int i = 0; i < aNumColumnsCompat; i++) {
            mEmojiList.add(new Emojicon(""));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This was the final solution I went with.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I can not answer your exact question

```
how can I add an empty row to this gridview with no regards to the number of items in the row?
```

But here are my thoughts. Firstly, how exactly are you adding the GridView to your view? As in how is the GridView getting visible at that place? Is that some view that is attached to the bottom of the activity, is it a popup? (I've never worked with making a custom keyboard of my own, so please excuse me if this sounds like a totally tupid irrelevant question)

Secondly, I know you dont want to consider the number of items in the row, but how about (as a workaround) get the number of items in a single row of your GridView and then try adding an empty row, based upon that number? In this way, it should work for all the different devices.

**EDIT:**
You can use the following code to get the number of columns in your GridView.

```
private int getNumColumnsCompat() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        return getNumColumnsCompat11();

    } else {
        int columns = 0;
        int children = getChildCount();
        if (children > 0) {
            int width = getChildAt(0).getMeasuredWidth();
            if (width > 0) {
                columns = getWidth() / width;
            }
        }
        return columns > 0 ? columns : AUTO_FIT;
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private int getNumColumnsCompat11() {
    return getNumColumns();
}
```

Comment: Well, the emoticons view is a popup that is presented on a long click of one of the buttons in the keyboard. I was trying to avoid the count of individual items in the row, but in case I won't find any way, how can I get the number of item in a row of a gridview?

Comment: Check my updated answer. And since its a popup, cant you position the popup a little higher in your activity? If you are using a [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) then you need to specify the x,y coordinates right? How about changing the y coordinate?

Comment: Yes I saw the updated answer I will test it in case I won't find a way to add a whole row. about the second part, as the semi-transparent view with the action buttons is part on the popup view, your suggestion won't do me any good in this case. But in any case thanks a lot for you help.  If I won't find any better option I will accept your answer.

Comment: Ohk yea got it, that popup y coordinate suggestion wont do any good here!